# xPosition and yPosition in mat-menu not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I tried xPosition and yPostion in angular material itself. but it is not working. I don't know whether am I missing something.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="after">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I referred few links which says the issue fixed. [Refere here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11668).

I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

This is a pain seriously, but i got a workaround. In a separate css file you can mention:

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
/* These numbers are my requirement, put something which suits yours */
  transform: translate(0px, 32px); 
}
```

But if even after this change you are facing this problem, then take it to next step to overlay panel:

```
::ng-deep.cdk-overlay-pane{
  transform: translate(0px, 32px);
}
```

Good Luck. Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, this works perfect, the second option. Didn't try the first since the menu are wrapped in .cdk-overlay-pane

Answer (score 1):

probably you solved it, but I'm posting this anyway, maybe it's useful for somebody.
If you follow [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) it should work perfectly (see [#customizing-menu-position section](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position)).
The reason it might not work probably depends on the position you put the menu in: for example, if you're trying to open it with yPosition=above, it has to have enough space to open above, otherwise it will open below. Same for the xPosition.
I know this might sound stupid but for me it was the reason it didn't work.
HTML:

```
    <button class="myButton" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu yPosition="above" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
```

CSS:

```
.myButton{
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

Comment: This solution wasn't "stupid" for me, or else maybe I'm stupid (a possibility) I copied my code from one spot where the menu button was at the left and I had xPosition="after" and that was fine for the original code, but when I copied it I had changed the button to be at the far right.   It took your answer for me to realize "oh yeah, I probably need xPosition to be set to "before" now.  Yup.  That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my styles CSS file worked seamlessly:

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly for me. You don't miss anything. Code is correct. It depends on orientation where you're trying to add.

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

In these images there're the same code,in first photo there's no place below the button.